# select element $(this).find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I am trying to get selected option values from the `select` element.

```
<form method="post" action="training/save" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="trainingForm">
  <select name="trainees[]" id="trainees" class="form-control" required multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>                    
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am getting `undefined` when trying to access the `select` values:

```
$('#trainingForm').submit( function (){
  console.log($(this).find('select[name="trainees"]').val());
});
```

I can get the values other way (by ID):

```
$('#trainees').val();
```

NOTE: `select2` is being used.

But I want to get the values in former way.

Comment: Use correct selector i.e. `select[name="trainees[]"]`

Comment: @Satpal my bad.. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is also the part of the *name* attribute of the element. You have to include that in the selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trainees').select2();
});

$('#trainingForm').submit( function (){
  console.log($(this).find('select[name="trainees[]"]').val());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="training/save" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="trainingForm">
    <select name="trainees[]" id="trainees" class="form-control" required multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your

```
$('#trainingForm').submit( function ()
{
  console.log($(this).find('select[name="trainees"]').val());
});
```

to

```
$('#trainingForm').submit( function ()
{
  console.log($(this).find('select[name="trainees[]"]').val());
});
```

You need to give same name as it is there in your html.